# How to set the default shown mailbox in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, default-settings

In my Outlook I use several accounts (one MS Exchange from Microsoft from my daughter) and some classic POP/SMTP accounts. When I open Outlook then the "wrong" mailbox is always shown by default. So, I always have switch to my personal mailbox.

Does anybody know how to set the default shown mailbox?

[image]

I remember in the past, it was the other way around. But I am not ware of any changes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Does anybody know how to set the default shown mailbox?

As follows:

- Open Outlook.
- Click on File.
- Click on Options.
- Click on Advanced.
- Under the "Outlook start and exit" section, click the Browse button.
- Select the folder that corresponds to the account you frequently use.
- Click the OK button.
- Click the OK button again.
- Restart the Outlook app.

Source: [How to set a new default account in Outlook | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-new-default-account-outlook) - includes images of key steps.

Comment: This setting is used to set the default "from" address, when you compose a new mail. It does not affect which mailbox is displayed when Outlook starts.

Comment: Ups, I did not scroll down in the page you liked. You set it in File -> Options -> Advanced -> Outlook start and exit -> Start Outlook in this folder.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. Answer updated.